# What is the frame rate of screen record

Tags: android, adb

I am using then adb screenrecord functionality to record a video of my game. I know that the default bitrate is 4Mbps. But what about the frame rate?
How can I know what is the frame and how to change it?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the frame rate may turn out to be a practical result of whatever if finds it can manage, not something you can set, and not something that is necessarily even steady within a given run.  If you are really curious, the source is presumably in AOSP to examine.

Comment: FWIW, source is here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/lollipop-release/cmds/screenrecord/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The frame rate is variable, not fixed. Every time the screen is updated, one frame is recorded.  If the screen is not updated, no frame is recorded.  Therefore there is no setting for the frame rate, because it's determined by how quickly the system updates the screen.

On most devices this will be a maximum of 60fps.  If you want to record at a lower rate, or have a fixed-rate video, you will need to use something like ffmpeg to convert it.

Some more information can be found on the [bigflake page](http://bigflake.com/screenrecord/).

To see this in action, you can enable the `--bugreport` flag in screenrecord v1.2 (first shipped in Android 5.0 "Lollipop").  This gives each individual frame a number and a timestamp.  You can see it in action in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udEwEKz149w).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The thing is that it seems it is recording at 16 frame per sec. I want it to be recorded at 24. If I convert the video, it will just be too short. So I want to keep the same length while it is in 24 fps. That's why I was asking if I can force it to be at least recording at 16fps (or if there is a way to do the conversion). Thanks again

Comment: If it's recording at 16fps, it's because your app is running at 16fps. So finding a way to speed up the app would be one approach. Another is to do a frame rate conversion like #2 here: http://www.hdslr-cinema.com/news/workflow/convert-between-framerates/ . I'm not an ffmpeg wizard, and that post is 5 years old, so there may be something better now -- most video editing software should be able to accept clips with different frame rates and combine them to a final product with a fixed frame rate.

Answer (score 10):

It is not possible to force frame rate value at the time the screen is being recorded. However, a lot of software have trouble in handling variable frame rate. The workaround I stumbled across is to use the `ffmpeg` command line utility and do something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i "test.mp4" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 15 -r 30 -threads 8 -c:a copy "test_new.mp4"
```

This will convert `test.mp4` video into `test_new.mp4` with a fixed frame rate of 30 fps.
I know the original question is quite old but maybe it will help someone.

Comment: I had to re-encode a video recorded with an app (variable framerate) to make it smaller. The resulting video had glitchy seeking (you go past a certain point the video exits even if it's not the end yet). The command you posted (`-r 30` part is key) is a lifesaver.

Comment: I have spent 2 years to figure out what the problem of the video and how to handle it properly in all kinda of different softwares. I knew it was variable frame rate, but it just doesn't work well sometimes and randomly. Finally, I found your answer. You save my life !!! Thank you very much for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few options in general when recording the screen. You can tack on a few modifiers to the ADB shell command like `--bit-rate` and `--size <WIDTHxHEIGHT>`. You can also change the maximum video length by using the `--time-limit <TIME>` command, but you have to do it ever single time. However, there's nothing you can do about screen rotation – it's not supported at all. If you do rotate the screen, part of the video will be cut off.
For example you can change the bit rate from 4mbps up to 8mbps by using
`adb shell screenrecord --bit-rate 8000000 /sdcard/pull_request.mp4`
See this [link](http://www.androidworks-kea.blogspot.ru/2013/11/developers-notes-iv-presets-for-screen.html?m=1) for details about supported resolutions, bitrates and problems. By using `adb screenrecord` you can change bitrate ONLY!!! 
Bitrate depends on the codec and the resolution. Framerate depends on the system work and changes during video playback!

About bitrate and framerate:
you can find the bitrate of uncompressed video using resolution and framerate, and lossless video through approximations, but lossy video's bitrate is framerate and res independent (well, save for quality/constant quant modes, but those aren't really predictable). Anyway
`Pixels width * pixels height * bits per pixel * framerate / 1024 bits in a kilobit` should do it for uncompressed
i.e. `640 * 480 * 24 (rgb) * 23.976 / 1024 = 172,627 kbps`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am not asking about the bit rate.  I am asking about how to know and/or change the frame rate

Comment: FWIW, as of screenrecord 1.1 (first shipped with Android 5.0 "Lollipop"), screen rotation is tracked. However, the mechanism used is imprecise and renders a couple of frames the wrong way.